# Google Cloud Platform Delete permanently a Image Disk

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created an image of my disk in my project, after I delete it, 
but somehow it still takes up disk space. How can i check it?

Answer (score 0):

1. List the disks in your project:

   ```
      gcloud compute disks list
      #disk-1                 us-central1-a   zone            500      pd-standard  READY
   ```
2. Create the image:

   ```
      gcloud compute images create new-disk --source-disk disk-1 --source-disk-zone  us-central1-a
      # Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/global/images/new-disk].
   ```
3. Delete the image:

   ```
      gcloud compute images delete new-disk
      # Deleted [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/global/images/new-disk]
   ```
4. Delete the disk:

   ```
      gcloud compute disks delete disk-1 --zone=us-central1-a
   ```
5. Check if the image was deleted:

   ```
      gcloud compute images list
   ```
6. Check if the disk was deleted:

   ```
      gcloud compute disks list
   ```

Comment: Please close off-topic questions.